# How to serve Mobile / Desktop on same URL wthout m.version nor Media queries?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, server

I want the same URL `website.com` serving *totally* different content based on whether mobile or not.

This means, **no** *CSS media queries*, and **no** *specific URL* `m.website.com`.

I don't even know if this is possible. But I think I have seen this on [this website](http://transit.loco.yahoo.co.jp/) (not sure).

In other words, imagine a "mobile" folder and a "desktop" folder on the server. 
Would it be possible to serve the content of "mobile" folder to the root `website.com/` if mobile, and serve desktop if not.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with PHP and the HTTP User Agent:

```
function find_mobile_browser()
{
  if(preg_match('/(alcatel|android|blackberry|benq|cell|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mobi|motorola|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|sagem|sharp|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|wireless|xda|zte)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Call this Function in the beginning of a code and it returns `True` if your user uses a Mobile User Agent. Ant then you can include the actual site. The `if`-Block could look like this: (Im not sure about the Include/Requested URI at the Moment)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI'] == ''){
  $request = index.html;
}
else{
  $request = $_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI'];
}
if(find_mobile_browsers()){
 include('mobile/'.$request);
}
else{
 include('desktop/'.$request;
}
```

Be Aware that the User Agent can be changed or doesn't get send to you but in this Case it would just return the Desktop Version.

For the `.htaccess` see this site: http://jrgns.net/redirect_request_to_index/

Comment: This may be good for a single page, but how would this allow me to entirely serve the content of `mobile/` folder ?

Comment: With the "include mobile" edit you just made, I think I understand better, let me check if this works : )

Comment: Put this in your Root Dir and Redirect all requests to this script with your .htaccess File. With the requested uri Field in the $_SERVER Array you can open the File that was called

Comment: After I fixed the typos in function names, I came across an error, so I changed a bit the code to : `include dirname(__FILE__).'/mobile/'.$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI'];` but I still get quite the same error : `Warning: main(/home/.sites/42/site27/web/mobile/) [function.main]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.sites/42/site27/web/index.php`. What is wrong?

Comment: My root is the `web/` folder. It runs from `index.php` in it. I added `dirname` (absolute path) to try to solve the problem as advised [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803261/warning-function-include-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: Why dont u use a relative Link?

Comment: Because I get the same error : `Warning: main(mobile/) [function.main]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.sites/42/site27/web/index.php` (this is what I get with `include 'mobile/'.$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI'];`)

Comment: What does it say when u echo `$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI']`?

Comment: Nothing (`NULL` with `var_dump`). Because I access the URL like this `website.com`

Comment: But it works when hard coded with `include 'mobile/index.html';`

Comment: Ok I found a workaround, I'll post an edit about that, but for your answer to be complete : how do you " Redirect all requests to this script with your .htaccess File" ?

Comment: Thank you. For the index.html problem, I came up with the exact same solution. For the `.htaccess`, I had to combine what I found in your link with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522921/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-single-page) to make it work. But then there is the final problem : all sources (img, css etc) are now broken because the url path has changed from `mobile/` to `root`. Any ideas ?

Comment: add `mobile/` in front of every URL

Comment: Yes of course. However, if I think more about that, shouldn't accesses to css files etc also be redirected ? Any way to do it with htaccess? Or I wont be able to work on the project locally with those new hard coded css urls...

Comment: ?? you can redirect css Files too but why?

Comment: If I add `mobile/` in front of every URL in the whole website, it will break my code when I work locally, and only work online. Which is quite inconvenient..!

Comment: I absolutly doesnt understand the Problem Sorry! Please open a new Question with your code etc.

Comment: Let me explain better. Now we have `website.com/mobile/index.html` displayed when accessing only `website.com`. So the URLs in it such as `css/style.css` are broken, because I guess it looks for it in `website.com/css/style.css` when it is actually in `website.com/mobile/css/style.css`

Comment: Thats right! What exactly is your htaccess at the Moment?Lets go into Chat => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69642/discussion-between-j-s-stack-and-lapin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69642/discussion-between-j-s-stack-and-lapin).